# Choice of database for a dictionary which can be edited as plain text

Tags: json, xml, database, csv

I am creating a dictionary app but I am not sure what kind of database to use !

My Requirements :

- Support for Unicode characters.
- Reasonably Fast search.
- In case of an installed version of the app, the database file can be edited using a text editor (such as notepad).
- I want to implement a web version of the app (WHICH USES THE SAME DATABASE FILE USED BY THE INSTALLED VERSION) and viewers can add/modify entries so it requires concurrent access via network.
- Easy to parse in any programming language.
- Expecting a maximum file size of 100 MB (May not reach anywhere near that but just to make it future proof.)

So with my limited knowledge I ended up with 3 options : CSV, XML or JSON. I prefer CSV for easy editing.

I understand that they are not as good as RDBMS but for the specific scenario is it possible to use any of these or how good can they perform?
Any alternate ideas are also welcome !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "In case of an installed version of the app, the database file can be edited using a text editor", why? As far as I know, no database can be edited using notepad. databases are storing data in a very structural manner where it can be traverse faster and efficiently.

Comment: Best database to use is Microsoft SQL Server.  You can download a free version of the database (SQL Express) which has most of the features of the full version and works in most applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using a single file as a "database" is not such a great choice if you think/plan to extend your application further.

My recommendation is SQLite (https://www.sqlite.org/about.html). As it is currently promoted on their website it's suitable on almost all of your requirements except that of being edited with a text editor. But I think that are easy enough solutions for content management as well, like SqliteBrowser http://sqlitebrowser.org/